# Как правильно сделать переход между экраном логина и другим экраном приложения в Delphi под Android?

Tags: android, delphi, экран, firemonkey

По умолчанию, новое приложение в Delphi для Android предлагает одну форму TForm1 на которой можно размещать элементы приложения. Мне нужно добавить шаг с авторизацией пользователя. По идее, кажется, что надо сделать 2 экрана/формы, первую с логином (TFormLogin) и вторую с непосредственно приложением (TFormMain). При старте приложения показывать экран/форму с логином, и после успешной валидации, менять экран/форму на основную.

Вопрос, а как правильно сделать переход между экраном логина и приложением в Delphi под Android? Правильно ли это делать через 2 формы, или лучше использовать какие-то другие способы? И как это примерно выглядит в коде?

Простое создание 2 форм и переключение через скрытие не работает (приложение закрывается)

```
FormLogin.Hide;
FormMain.Show;
```

Вот такой вариант работает, но выглядит не совсем правильно:

```
FormLogin.GroupBox1.Visible := False; // все элементы лежат на GroupBox1
FormMain.Parent := FormLogin;
FormMain.Show;
```

Comment: Не работает потому что `ShowModal` это не тоже само что `Show` и работает иначе от слова совсем.

Comment: Я вам указал на то что ваш пример 100% не заработает по причине того что `formLogin.Hide` - делает `hide` для всех дочерних форм(`ShowModal` - отображает окно как дочернее).

Comment: FormMain не является дочерней по отношению к FormLogin. Если так будет спокойнее, то я ShowModal из вопроса уберу )

Comment: то что вы знали о работе Delphi в Windows системах - забудьте, в андроиде логика иная, и ShowModal работает по "андроидовскому" =) погодите 5 минут, скачается SDK на этот Пк, открою примеры и вспомню как правильно делается переход с формы на форму =)

Comment: Поэтому и спрашиваю. И пожалуйста, забудьте про ShowModal, он к вопросу не относится.

Comment: Тот же вопрос на англ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554417

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой вариант переключения выглядит достаточно правильным с точки зрения логики и даже вроде бы корректно работает:

```
// Create only FormLogin on app creation
// Create FormMain on successfull login

Application.CreateForm(TFormMain, FormMain);
FormMain.Show;
Application.MainForm := FormMain;
FormLogin.Close;
FormLogin.Free;
FormLogin := nil;
```